# With nvd3.js/d3.js, how can you have a scatter or line chart with discrete/non-numeric/non-time-series X-Axis values?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

For example, I want a scatter chart that looks like:

```
   100|        X                                           o
      |                                      o
    60|
      |        o             X               X                 
    40|
      |
    20|                      o                             X
      |
     0|______________________________________________________________
             Apples        Carrots        Dragons        Monkies
```

Where X and o are different sets of data

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use an ordinal sale for the x axis. Ordinal scales are constructed by calling `d3.scale.ordinal()`. The `domain` would be an array of your titles (you can use the native `map` method on your array of data to pull out the titles dynamically). The `range` needs to by an array of the same length as the `domain` array, specifying each xcoordinate in pixels that will correspond to the titles.

See this example here: http://tributary.io/inlet/5788637

You can fork it and try adding a yScale (in this case it will be constructed by `d3.scale.linear` since it is a continous number scale) and making a y axis following a similar pattern as the x axis.